# How to iterate a Map in JSON , when the values contains a List and the reference to the List is NULL

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

This class returns the JSON string, But the Map values which contains the List is returning NULL pointer exception.

Tried the various options mentioned, still getting the same null pointer exception.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

public class JacksonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Map<String, Foo> foos = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
    foos.put("foo1", new Foo("foo1"));
    foos.put("foo2", new Foo(List<DetailMessage>));
    foos.put("foo3", null);
    foos.put(null, new Foo("foo4"));

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    // Since the DetailMessage field is null , Its throwing Null pointer //exception.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem you are having is because of the `null` value as key in the Map, the default JSON structure is something like this

```
{
   "Key1" : "Value1",
   "Key2" : "Value2"...
} (This is the simplest form)
```

In JSON we can't have anything like `null : "value"` this violates the basic JSON principle hence Object Mapper is not able to convert your Map to JSON String, you need to have all non-null keys in the map, for this to work

so removing the line `foos.put(null, new Foo("foo4"));` will make your code work

Even if Map allows 1 NULL key, JSON doesn't conform to it, so you are facing this error

Hope it helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks , I am facing exception in line foos.put("foo2", new Foo(List<DetailMessage>)); Null pointer as field is not set .

Comment: it is the same error I guess, you need to show what code is present in `DetailMessage` and how you are actually inserting in the map
`foos.put("foo2", new Foo(List<DetailMessage>))` should be a compilation error in normal situations

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JasonMappingException:(was java.lang .NullPointerException) (through reference chain:java.util.HashMap["DetailMesage"]->java..util.ArrayList[0]->com.test.container.DetailMessage[fileMapper1])